# Migrating from IDEA to Android Studio with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have migrated my project from IDEA to Android Studio to use Gradle.
I have successfully build the App (haven't looked at the tests yet) and now want to include product flavours (my reason for moving).

I can now select one of four build variants in the "Build Variants" menu, and building with the new settings renders a new App on my Phone, so that seems all ok.

However, where do I make the changes to the sources (with the original directory structure) or do I need to change it? What is the best way? (I don't have the structure /src/xxx/res, just src/org/bla/bla)

The main changes are to resources like string files and graphics.
Thanks!

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.+'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.2.+'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        //versionName "0.5"
    }

    productFlavors {
        iDomsPortalDev {
            packageName 'org.idoms.iDomsAndroid.iDomsPortalDev'
        }
        iDomsPortal {
            packageName 'org.idoms.iDomsAndroid.iDomsPortal'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packageNameSuffix ".debug"
            //versionNameSuffix "-debug"
        }
        release {
            packageNameSuffix ".release"
            //versionNameSuffix "-release"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
        iDomsPortal.setRoot('product-flavors/iDomsPortal')
        iDomsPortalDev.setRoot('product-flavors/iDomsPortalDev')

}
println "main: " + android.sourceSets.main.res.srcDirs

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        println variant.name + ": " + android.sourceSets[variant.name].res.srcDirs
    }

    android.productFlavors.all { flavor ->
        println flavor.name + ": " + android.sourceSets[flavor.name].res.srcDirs
    }

    android.buildTypes.all { buildType ->
        println buildType.name + ": " + android.sourceSets[buildType.name].res.srcDirs
    }
```

[EDIT: updated data above and put the code to printed the output AFTER the changes and now it works!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're asking where you put flavor-specific reources; if you're asking where to make changes to the main sources and resources, that's in the directory structure you mapped out under `sourceSets.main`.

You can add this bit of script to the top level of your **build.gradle** file (e.g. after the `android` block) to print out the directories where it will look for resources:

```
println "main: " + android.sourceSets.main.res.srcDirs

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    println variant.name + ": " + android.sourceSets[variant.name].res.srcDirs
}

android.productFlavors.all { flavor ->
    println flavor.name + ": " + android.sourceSets[flavor.name].res.srcDirs
}

android.buildTypes.all { buildType ->
    println buildType.name + ": " + android.sourceSets[buildType.name].res.srcDirs
}
```

This outputs the flavor-specific resource directories, and also the build variant (flavor + build type directories).

When I run them on your build file, I get:

```
main: [/Users/sbarta/AndroidStudioProjects/AS_Eclipse/app/res]
app1: [/Users/sbarta/AndroidStudioProjects/AS_Eclipse/app/src/app1/res]
app2: [/Users/sbarta/AndroidStudioProjects/AS_Eclipse/app/src/app2/res]
debug: [/Users/sbarta/AndroidStudioProjects/AS_Eclipse/app/build-types/debug/res]
release: [/Users/sbarta/AndroidStudioProjects/AS_Eclipse/app/build-types/release/res]
app1Debug: [/Users/sbarta/AndroidStudioProjects/AS_Eclipse/app/src/app1Debug/res]
app1Release: [/Users/sbarta/AndroidStudioProjects/AS_Eclipse/app/src/app1Release/res]
app2Debug: [/Users/sbarta/AndroidStudioProjects/AS_Eclipse/app/src/app2Debug/res]
app2Release: [/Users/sbarta/AndroidStudioProjects/AS_Eclipse/app/src/app2Release/res]
```

The directory for **main** is expected -- that's what's explicitly set in `sourceSets.main`. The **debug** and **release** types we see remapped to the *build-types* directory as per the statements at the end of your `sourceSets` block. For the **app1** and **app2** flavors, it's looking in *src/app1* and *src/app2*, which is probably not what you want. I'd recommend moving the entire root directory for your flavors, similar to how you do for the build types. I'd change that block at the end to:

```
// Move the build types to build-types/<type>
// For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
// This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
// conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
// Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
// by a similar customization.
debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
release.setRoot('build-types/release')
app1.setRoot('product-flavors/app1')
app2.setRoot('product-flavors/app2')
```

As for the variants, **app1Debug** et al, you maybe don't have to worry about them, unless you're doing something so specific that you really need to override on that detailed a basis. At any rate, now when I run and look at my diagnostic output, I see:

```
main: [/Users/sbarta/AndroidStudioProjects/AS_Eclipse/app/res]
app1: [/Users/sbarta/AndroidStudioProjects/AS_Eclipse/app/product-flavors/app1/res]
app2: [/Users/sbarta/AndroidStudioProjects/AS_Eclipse/app/product-flavors/app2/res]
debug: [/Users/sbarta/AndroidStudioProjects/AS_Eclipse/app/build-types/debug/res]
release: [/Users/sbarta/AndroidStudioProjects/AS_Eclipse/app/build-types/release/res]
app1Debug: [/Users/sbarta/AndroidStudioProjects/AS_Eclipse/app/src/app1Debug/res]
app1Release: [/Users/sbarta/AndroidStudioProjects/AS_Eclipse/app/src/app1Release/res]
app2Debug: [/Users/sbarta/AndroidStudioProjects/AS_Eclipse/app/src/app2Debug/res]
app2Release: [/Users/sbarta/AndroidStudioProjects/AS_Eclipse/app/src/app2Release/res]
```

Comment: That looks really good. I applied your suggestion to my project and updated the build.gradle. However, it does not seem to take the changes in account in the out in the console. I updated the listing of the build.gradle above too and posted the output (note, this is not from my App, so the real names are in there now, not app1 app2)

Comment: Never mind. Off course, I should have inserted the commenting AFTER changing the root! Great answer! Thanks a million!